# Trying to retrieve url metadata in Express/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, meta-tags

I have a resource that contains a URL field entered by the user. I am trying to use this package: https://github.com/mozilla/page-metadata-parser to retrieve the title and description associated with the URL, and save this to the db on creation.

I have added the code modeled in the package documentation to the post request in Express and there are no errors, the new bookmark is created but the meta data values do not get returned.

Here is my model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const BookmarksSchema = new Schema({
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
  },
  url: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },

...

  title: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: false
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: false
  }
});

mongoose.model('Bookmarks', BookmarksSchema);
```

my create method:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const router = require('express').Router();
const auth = require('../auth');
const Bookmarks = mongoose.model('Bookmarks');

router.post('/', auth.required, (req, res, next) => {
  const userId = req.user.id;
  const bookmark = req.body.bookmark;

  if (!bookmark.url) {
    return res.status(422).json({
      errors: {
        url: 'is required',
      },
    });
  }

  const { getMetadata } = require('page-metadata-parser');
  const domino = require('domino');

  const url = bookmark.url;
  const response = fetch(url);
  const html = response.text();
  const doc = domino.createWindow(html).document;
  const metadata = getMetadata(doc, url);

  bookmark.userId = userId;
  bookmark.title = metadata.title;
  bookmark.description = metadata.description;

  const finalBookmark = new Bookmarks(bookmark);

  return finalBookmark.save()
    .then(() => res.json({ bookmark: finalBookmark }));
});
```

and package.json:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "domino": "^2.1.3",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.20",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "page-metadata-parser": "^1.1.3",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon app"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Took a look at the documentation and I saw that the `fetch(url)` call is preceded by the keyword `await`.  Try putting that in your code and running it again.  I'm willing to bet that `fetch` is an asynchronous method that requires you use `await` to resolve the promise before moving forward in the code.

Comment: I did that at first, but where do I need to put the `async` call?

Comment: The keyword `async` would go at the declaration of the anonymous callback function in the router.  Looks like around line `7` right before `(req, res, next)`.  Pop that keyword in and see if it works.

Comment: That works. Thanks! I changed the post request to be: `router.post('/', auth.required, async function (req, res, next) {`. Then I had to add node-fetch module. You helped me greatly. If you make this an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Glad it's working for you. Went ahead and posted a little more in depth answer with more code so it would help more folks later who look at it.  Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the answer here so we can mark the answer as correct.

The error arose due to the fact that the call to `fetch()` was an asynchronous call and the keyword `await` was not being used.  The example on the NPM site found here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/page-metadata-parser

Shows that they used `await` on the `fetch()` call.  In order to use `await` the anonymous callback function, the function that starts with `(req, res, next)` has to have the keyword `async` in front of it.  The call should then look like this:

```
router.post('/', auth.required, async (req, res, next) => {
     // Do your stuff here as before.
     const url = bookmark.url;
     const response = await fetch(url);
     const html = response.text();
     const doc = domino.createWindow(html).document;
     const metadata = getMetadata(doc, url);
     // Finish stuff here.
});
```

Now response is being populated and the program waits until the `fetch` call is complete before moving forward, thus filling out the remaining variables and being able to grab the meta data.